# Helping non mahram

Tags: non-mahram, helping, touching

In the matter of life, and death, Is it halal to help a non mahram in a situation where touching one another is required (without touching you may not be able to help)?

Comment: what's the situation?

Comment: Would you just leave somebody die ... what is the greater sin?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

A good article on this is

https://www.islamicinsights.com/features/islam-and-the-importance-of-first-aid.html

It quotes (unfortunately without reference)

> Muslim women volunteered as nurses at war.

It's quite evident from the Quran, Hadith and prior revelation that saving lives has priority over other prescriptions.

Answer (score 1):

> It has been narrated on the authority of Anas b. Malik who said that
> the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) allowed Umm Sulaim and some other women of
> the Ansar to accompany him when he went to war; they would give water
> (to the soldiers) and would treat the wounded. https://sunnah.com/muslim:1810